# Print web response in <code> format Google app engine python project

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am beginner to Google App engine. Doing a project that takes user query and print response. I used `self.response.write('<code>{'+q+'}{'+str(code)+'}</code>')` this way to print my response and when I read it it comes like `<code>{pi}{3.14159265359}</code>`. I need the response should be shown in  format but  tag should not come in response. How to do it.

Please conside this URL : http://ishamsample.appspot.com/eval?q=pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the response content type to, for example, `text/plain`:

```
...
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
self.response.write('{'+q+'}{'+str(code)+'}')
```

there are many different formats you can use like `application/xml` or `application/json`.